# putting answers in comments

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

When someone puts their answer to a question as a comment on the question, does that mean that the question was a bad question?  Does it have any particular meaning?  I don't see how I could mark that answer as an answer to my question if the answer is in a comment.  Is it always bad practice to do this?

Comment: see [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238/579) for an extended discussion of this phenomenon.

Comment: You can always ask a commenter to turn their comment into a question (it helps if you tell them you'll accept it if they do so).

Comment: Sometimes, it's juste a way to see if the OP have tried a solution that can be proposed after.

Comment: Some users asking questions add new questions in comments to the answers to their questions, thereby often changing the question completely. It's quite natural that short comments are sometimes better than to provide 'big' answers